# Is there any way to fill FacebookSettings.asset with script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Is there any way to fill this with a editor script?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/blob/master/Facebook.Unity/Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs#L91

Comment: Thanks. Very helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely sure you can't. Your facebook app id is strongly bound to your **Package ID** (android) / **Bundle ID** (iOS) / or **some other app ID** (other platforms). Even when you are developing a native application you have to have the fb ID explicitly declared in your app before build.

You may be able to write an editor script to call it inside unity editor, I don't know anything about that. But again, you can not set an fb ID during runtime, or change it.